# How do I fix the terminal problem in launching C exes using vs code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Both templates of `launch.json` don't work. None of the configs print anything in console.

I have made a folder full of C programs and I want to run those programs using vs code (one by one ofc). I am facing problems while using the `windows` template of `launch.json` since it needs exact filename of executables while I need that `launch.json` for the whole folder.
So I chose the `GDB/LLDB` one but it is not working well even with `"externalConsole" = true`.
The terminal closes in a splitsecond. I saw many similar questions but none of them had the answer I needed.

`Launch.json`:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:\\MinGW64\\bin",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

`Tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: I only see 1 `launch.json`

Comment: yea cuz I didn't use the windows one

Comment: `Task generated by Debugger.` is the wrong description: `gcc` is the compiler not the debugger, the label says it all, that task is not generated by a debugger

Comment: That's the default template.
It is not edited and it was generated by vscode not gcc